# How to mute Notification Sound in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing application, in that I'm using push notification. For that I want to add setting to enable/disable notification sound. I am used ToggleButton for Yen/No.
Now on Yes, I declared,

```
`defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;`
```

But when it NO, i dono how to  **Mute** it.
Please give me suggestions to mute sound.

Answer (score 0):

Add this before:

```
myNotification.defaults = 0;
myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE
Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
Notification.DEFAULT_ALL
```